# Forum design suggestions

Tags: database-design, forum

I'm doing a forum script in php, i'm trying to think the best way to flag topics each user has read or not.

Once the user logins into forum i can mark what's been read or not depending on his last login time, that's fine, now what's the best approach to mark each topic each user clicks?

I was thinking in adding cookies but that would lead to a security issue and might not be accurate, specially if the user logins from another machine/browser.

I also thought of adding a special database table with each topic each user has clicked, that also sounded bad for me due the incrase on cpu usage and database growth.

Anyone has a better suggestion/solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Better suggestion: don't bother. Forum software is a solved problem with plenty of off the shelf code available for use. Getting forum software to work robustly in an environment (the web) where anything can and does happen takes literal years of field exposure.

Comment: Tell that to the Stack Overflow team.  Let's play along, though, and assume that he's doing this for educational puposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a separate database table to keep a record for every topic X every user if the user has read it (no record if the user hasn't), and then automatically assume after 30 days that the topic is read, which allows you to prune this table to prevent overgrowth.  Keeping a separate table like this is pretty standard practice, and unless this forum is super popular (always plan for popularity I guess), I doubt you'll run into space or CPU limits.

For example, table `topics_read` has fields `user_id`, `topic_id`, and `when`.  Storing two ints and a date is only a few bytes for each row.